# Weblist object array in UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Below is the code that I have written for identifying objects on a browser.

```
Set oBrowser = Browser("Creationtime:=0").Page("Index:=0")
Set objWEdit = Description.Create
objWEdit("micclass").value="WebEdit"
Set objEdit = oBrowser.ChildObjects(objWEdit)
```

I have some data added in the data table to be filled in for these WebEdit's. I am able to use a **For Next** loop to do this. Is there a way to do it using **For Each In** loop. Am not sure if the objEdit can be used as an object array?

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by `ChildObjects` is not a VBScript array, it's a COM object that supports indexing and `.Count`.

You'll have to use `For ... Next`.

```
For i = 0 To objEdit.Count -1
    Set oEdit = objEdit(i)
    ' use oEdit here
Next
```